# How do I put this in the tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can you please show me how to put this query in the tables..

```
<?
$username="root";
$password="kermit";
$database="moodle";


mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "SELECT user.firstname, user.lastname, stats.userid, stats.roleid, SUM(   statsreads ) AS numreads, SUM( statswrites ) AS numwrites, SUM( statsreads ) + SUM( statswrites ) AS totalactivity FROM  `mdl_stats_user_daily` stats, `mdl_user` user WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid FROM mdl_role_assignments WHERE roleid IN (1,2,3,4)) AND user.id = stats.userid AND stats.timeend > ".(time() - 604800)." GROUP BY userid ORDER BY totalactivity DESC";


result=mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close();
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you're missing a '$' in front of 'result=...'. It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to take the results of the SELECT query and insert that data into some other table? Assuming 'other_table' has the appropriate schema, then it's potentially as simple as prefixing your like this: $query = "INSERT INTO other_table ( SELECT user.firstname,....)"'

Comment: what I mean in here is how do I put the generated result on my HTML tables...

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the mysql_fetch_array function, your table population should go wrapped within a block like this for example:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["firstname"]."</td></tr>";
}
```

But, since you're new to MySQL, my best advice to you is to learn how to use the MySQL via the PDO namespace first up, before you make using the above a habit.

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers